# MultiPublisher-MultiConsumer Queue using Redis

Tags: redis, queue, microservices, message-queue

1. I have multiple Monitoring Service `MonSvc(1..N)` those detects changes and publish those changes.
2. I multiple services that operate on those updates (e.g. `LoggerSvc` & `Enforcement-Svc`)

   > *Note: Consumer services needs all updates, and cannot miss an update.*

I am using *Redis* as my Coordinator(broker) but i am a bit confused about how should i implement it.

**Option 1: Each MonSvc# publish updates to Redis Channel, while monitor services subscribe**
 this design fails because if the Consumer service goes down, it might miss an update that it cannot retrieve later on

**Option 2: Each MonSvc# Enqueue updates to Redis List(Queue), while Consumers take elements from queue**
Consumers don't take all updates, but each gets a partial list.

**Option 3: Each MonSvc# Enqueue updates to multiple Redis Lists(Queues) (queue/consumer), while Consumers take elements from queues**
This works fine, but seems to scale poorly (MonSvc# need to know who is it publishing to + how many)

How can I have a *"Multi-Publisher >> Multi-Consumer Queue"* with Redis (or should i use a stronger broker?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for Redis Streams with Consumer Groups, introduced in Redis 5.0. See here: https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro

There is an excellent free [course for this is Redis University](https://university.redislabs.com/courses/course-v1:redislabs+RU202+2020_02/about), recommended.

With Redis Streams, you can achieve the at-least-once delivery semantics you're looking for.

See the key consumer group commands:

> - [`XGROUP`](https://redis.io/commands/xgroup) is used in order to create, destroy and manage consumer groups.
> - [`XREADGROUP`](https://redis.io/commands/xreadgroup) is used to read from a stream via a consumer group.
> - [`XACK`](https://redis.io/commands/xack) is the command that allows a consumer to mark a pending message as correctly processed.

Comment: looks promising, Thanks.